# Graph question proof relating complete graphs and girth

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

If graph $G$ has girth $\ge 4$ and $|V(G)| = n$ for even $n$ and $|E(G)| = \frac{n^2}{4}$, then $G$ is isomorphic to $K_{\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2}}$. In order to show isomorphic, I need to show there is a bijective function. However, $K_{\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2}}$ also has $\frac{n}{2}+\frac{n}{2} = n$ vertices and $\frac{n^2}{4}$ edges. The degree of any one vertex is $\frac{n}{2}$. How do I show this is true for $G$. Does it help prove the isometry? Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: first show that the average degree of $G$ is $\frac{n}{2}$.
Then show that there cannot be a vertex of strictly smaller degree
(by assuming there is such a vertex $v$, counting edges in $G-v$ and using Mantel's theorem).
This means that $G$ must be regular.